# Show that Lagrange multiplier is the optimal value

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I am trying to solve the following problem.

Minimize $$f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$$

Subject to $$g(x,y) = ax^2 +2bxy +cy^2-1 = 0$$
$$(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}$$
Where $$a>0,c>0,2b>a+c$$
a) Use Lagrange theorem to show that $\exists$ $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $Df(x^*,y^*) = \lambda Dg(x^*,y^*)$

This is simple because we have non degenerate constraint qualification .

b) use a) to show that $\lambda = f(x^*,y^*)$.

This is the part that I am stuck on I have written the Lagrangian and the FOC’s but I couldn’t figure out how to show this part, I tried inverting $Dg(x^*,y^*)$ in the equation in part a) but realized it is a vector and can’t (in general) be inverted, I also know that $f(x^*,y^*) >0$ because of the constraint, can someone please provide the solution .

IMPORTANT-
Please note that I am not to just solve the FOC’s along with the constraint find $(x^*,y^*)$ and find the optimal value then show that result in b) holds, the question uses the result of part b) to find $f(x^*,y^*)$ directly without finding $(x^*,y^*)$

Comment: This doesn't make sense as a general rule, If the cost is replaced by $f+c$ where $c$ is some constant then the solution will not change and the multiplier will remain the same, but the optimal cost has shifted by $c$. So Part b) would seem to be specific to this particular problem.

Comment: Yes I’m pretty sure it is specific to this problem, but do you know how to show this?

Comment: I added a solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $A>0$ is symmetric. Let $f(x) = x^T x$ and $g(x) = x^TAx -1$, then
if $x^*$ is a solution to $\min \{ f (x) | g(x) = 0 \}$ we have
$g(x^*) = 0$ and $Df(x^*) = \lambda Dg(x^*)$. Expanding gives
$x^*= \lambda Ax^*$ and so $(x^*)^T x^* = \lambda (x^*)^T Ax^* = \lambda$. Hence $f(x^*) = \lambda$.

Comment: Can you please explain -expanding gives$x^* = \lambda Ax^*$ what exactly are we expanding?

Comment: $Df(x^*) = (x^*)^T, Dg(x^*) = (x^*)^T A$. Taking transposes the Lagrange equation gives $x^* = \lambda Ax^*$.

Comment: Sorry for the following silly question but $T$ here means transpose right?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Ok thanks man, appreciate your patience

Comment: @user601297: Glad to be able to help.